# Get a single element of CSV file

Tags: c#, string, list, csv, split

I'm trying to add some csv elements to a list of Alimento, where Alimento is declared as:

```
namespace ContaCarboidrati
{
    class Alimento
    {
       public virtual string Codice { get; set; }
       public virtual string Descrizione { get; set; }
       public virtual int Carboidrati { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My csv looks something like this:

`"C00, Pasta, 75"`.

Here's the method that should create the list from the csv:

```
private static List<Alimento> CreaListaAlimentiDaCsv()
{        
   List<Alimento> listaCsv = new List<Alimento>();
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Alex\Documents\RecordAlimenti.csv");
   string abc = sr.ReadLine();
   //listaCsv = abc.Split(",");
}
```

abc is "C00, Pasta, 75". I want to get a single element to add it to the list, or add all the 3 elements to the list, i thought that a single element is easier to made.

Sorry for my bad English

Thanks in advance

Alex

Comment: And what's the problem with the commented code you have with the Split method? Split returns an array, so listaCsv[], but otherwise, it seems fine. Then you'd loop through the array and assign each item to Codice, Descrizione and Carboidrati. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: For working with CSVs, better use some library like [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: CSV records can span multiple lines (you can have line breaks in quoted fields), reading line by line won't help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you cannot just create an Alimento of three strings, which is what you will get if you do abc.Split(","). You need to create a new Alimento object for each item (line) in the csv file and initialize each object correctly. Something like this:

```
var item = abc.Split(',');
listaCsv.Add(new Alimento() { Codice = item[0], Descrizione = item[1], 
Carboidrati = int.Parse(item[2])};
```

Also, your csv seems to include spaces after the commas which you might want to get rid of. You could use string.Trim() to get rid of leading/trailing spaces. You also have to make sure the third item is actually an integer and take action if that is not the case (i.e. add some error handling).

As a side note, implementing a csv reader is not as trivial as one may think, but there are several free C# implementations out there. If you need something a bit more advanced than just reading a simple (and strictly one-line-per-item) csv, try one of these:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader
- http://www.filehelpers.com/

Comment: +1 for providing a simple solution that fits in his existing code

Comment: It gives an error con "var item = abc.Split(",");"

argument 1: impossible to cast from "string" to "Char[]"

Comment: @user1711154 Sorry, changed the code, it should state abc.Split(','); I.e. use single quotes. Single quotes will create a char, which is what we want here. Double-quotes = a string.

Comment: Commas are not necessary, I can cancel them

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECTLY. THANKS A LOT! This is the simplest way so i mark is as answer

Comment: Good luck! I added a couple of links to some free C# csv readers in case you run into cases where you need some extra "power".

Answer (score 1):

You can parse file with LINQ

```
var listaCsv = (from line in File.ReadAllLines("RecordAlimenti.csv")
                let items = line.Split(',')
                select new Alimento {
                      Codice = items[0],
                      Descrizione = items[1],
                      Carboidrati = Int32.Parse(items[2])
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it pretty easy assuming your data isn't bad.

```
private IEnumerable<Alimento> CreaListaAlimentiDaCsv(string fileName)
{        
    return File.Readlines(fileName) //@"C:\Users\Alex\Documents\RecordAlimenti.csv"
               .Select(line => line.Split(',').Trim())
               .Select(
                    values =>
                        new Alimento
                            {
                                Codice = value[0],
                                Descrizione  = values[0],
                                Carboidrati = Convert.ToInt32(values[3])
                            });
}
```

You can also use Linq on the method such as

```
//Takes one line without iterating the entire file
CreaListaAlimentiDaCsv(@"C:\Users\Alex\Documents\RecordAlimenti.csv").Take(1); 

//Skips the first line and takes the second line reading two lines total
CreaListaAlimentiDaCsv(@"C:\Users\Alex\Documents\RecordAlimenti.csv").Skip(1).Take(1);
```